# a proof in variable separation method for 2-D heat equation

Tags: calculus

when solving the PDF of 2D heat equation
$U_t= C (U_{xx}+U_{yy})$, via classic separation method to set $U_{(x,y,t)}=X_{(x)}Y_{(y)}T_{(t)}$, then by plugging into the PDE, we may have the following expression: $$\frac{T'}{CT}=\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}=constant -(1)$$

I saw the material I have starts to have two ODE:$$X''-AX=0-(2)$$ $$Y''-BY=0-(3)$$
Here comes my question: is there a way to prove $\frac{X''}{X}$ and $\frac{Y''}{Y}$ has to be constants because of (1) so that the (2),(3) is therefore derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a variation of the usual argument: you have
$$
\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = \lambda - \frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}
$$
where the left-hand side is independent of $y$ and the right-hand side is independent of $x$, so that both sides must be constant, say equal to $A$. Then you get the ODEs that you wrote, if you let $B=\lambda-A$.

Comment: Thanks. Sample and helpful for me.